# Is there a way with numpy to memmap a big-endian complex number?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I'm trying to load data from very large files that are formatted to be complex64 but in big-endian. Because of their size I want to use memmap. I can load the array as big-endian floats like such:

```
arr = np.memmap(fn, dtype='>f4', shape=(M,N,2))
```

but if I try to get a view of it as a complex number it reverts the byteswapping ie

```
arr[m,n,0]+1j*arr[m,n,1] != arr[m,n].view(dtype=np.complex64)
```

but

```
arr[m,n,0]+1j*arr[m,n,1] == arr[m,n].view(dtype=np.complex64).byteswap()
```

But this either creates a copy of the data or modifies the files. Is there a way to make this work without making a copy of the data or modifying the existing files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the .byteswap() method doesn't modify or copy the data. So

narr = arr[m,n].view(dtype=np.complex64).byteswap()

Is the way to go. Hopefully that helps someone else.